# Create indexes to Extract information on a Particular date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have created two tables.

Events:

```
Create Table Events
(EventID int identity (2001,1) CONSTRAINT pkeventid PRIMARY KEY
, EventName nvarchar(50) not null 
, StartDate datetime not null
, CustomerID int CONSTRAINT fkcustomerID REFERENCES 
  Customer(CustomerID)
```

Customer:

```
Create Table Customer
(CustomerID int identity (4001,1) CONSTRAINT pkcusid PRIMARY KEY
, Name nvarchar(50) not null 
, Address nvarchar(50) not null 
, City nvarchar(50) not null 
, State nvarchar(50) not null
```

How can I create an index to extract customer details for an event organized on a particular date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you may be confusing a query and an index. At the basic level, the query is what joins the records together, applies the filters (such as event date), identifies what parts of the records to return, and sorts them. An index is something that helps the database engine organize and store parts of records that make some queries perform faster.

The query below should help get you started. You're looking for an `INNER JOIN` to join your events and customers. Then you need the `WHERE` to filter the results for the start date.

```
SELECT *
FROM Customer
    INNER JOIN Events
        ON Events.CustomerID = Customer.CustomerID
WHERE CONVERT(DATE, Events.StartDate) = '2015-01-15'
```

You may want to just google some tutorials on learning SQL (specifically with the SELECT, JOIN, and WHERE) to get started. Some of these may help:

- http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_intro.asp
- http://sqlzoo.net/